# Active admin Index page hide column based on condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

Active admin index page i want to hide the column based on some condition , but the below code is not wokrking.

```
index title: 'Comp-Off', download_links: false do
    selectable_column
    if proc{ !(current_user.has_role? :Employee) }
      column("Name", sortable: :name)      {|resource| resource.employee.name}
      column("ID", sortable: :employee_id) {|resource| resource.employee.employee_id}
    end
    column :status
end
```

How to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is achieved using the below code.

```
index title: 'Comp-Off', download_links: false do
    selectable_column
    column("Name", sortable: :name)      {|resource| resource.employee.name} if !(current_user.has_role? :HRMS_Employee)
    column("ID", sortable: :employee_id) {|resource| resource.employee.employee_id} if !(current_user.has_role? :HRMS_Employee)
    end
    column :status
end
```